# The order type of a countable union of finite sets of ordinals

Tags: set-theory

Assume that we work in ZFC.

What is the least upper bound of $\{\text{order-type}(\bigcup_{n \in \omega} X_n) : X_0, X_1, \ldots$ are finite sets of ordinals}?

Comment: The "least"? $\varnothing$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is it an upper bound?

Comment: Ah, I misread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is countable, you can enumerate it, and split it to finite sets, in fact singletons. And clearly, you cannot split $\omega_1$ into countably many finite sets.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: An ordinal, clearly. But any countable order works here.